# How to read a reactive expression from reactivefilereader?

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity, readr

I try to develop a shiny interface which display a graph updated each time the file is change.
For this, I read the file with reactivefilereader.
Then, I read the result of this with a read_csv to skip some lines to be able to display the graph correctly.
That was working with the 1.4 version of the readr package, this is not working anymore with version 2.0.X.
How can I read the reactive expression as a csv file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
chemin_min_rea <- reactiveFileReader(1000, NULL,chemin_min, readLines)
```

and then :

```
read_csv(chemin_min_rea, col_types = cols(.default = "c"), skip = 1 )
```

do :

```
chemin_min_rea <- reactiveFileReader(1000, 
                                NULL,
                                chemin_min, 
                                read_csv, 
                                col_types = cols(.default = "c"), 
                                skip = 1 )
```

Done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).